# Continuos active pattern match with list for F#

Tags: f#

I have this pattern for a compiler, and in the expr parser I want to do this

```fs
let (|InfixOperator|_|) tokens = ...

let (|UnaryValue|_|) tokens = ...

let infixExpr tokens =
  match tokens with
  | Value v::Operator op::tokens -> ...
  | Value v::tokens -> ...
```

The problem is that either the tokens for the match expr have a signature of `Token list list` or the pattern Value (needs to receive a list since it parses unary operations) does not give back the remaining tokens, the same happens for the Operator pattern

The ugly way around it would be something like this

```
let (|InfixOperator|_|) tokens = ...

let (|UnaryValue|_|) tokens = ...

let infixExpr tokens =
  match tokens with
  | Value (v, Operator (op, tokens)) -> ...
  | Value (v, tokens) -> ...
```

Does anyone know any cleaner way of doing this with pattern matching?

Comment: I think there's not enough information here to answer the question. Can you clarify why `Value` takes a list of tokens instead of a single token? And if `Value` really does match a list of tokens, how can `v` be a single token?

Comment: Value is a simplification of Unary expression so it takes unary operators and a value (bool for this case) and return a parsed expression that is the value for the final infix expression.

Comment: Pattern matches are generally not a good fit for a parser. You'll run into more problems later. The accepted, well working approach for parsers is a monadic interface.

Comment: now I am already re-writing the parser to have a similar use as fparsec (can't use it directly since I am using fable), but the question stays there so I can know how to do this since I gotten against it in other cenerios and had to restructure the whole project to fit this one incapability

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a parser for a subset of BASIC that uses pattern matching ([source code is available on GitHub](https://github.com/tpetricek/basic/blob/master/src/App.fs)). This is not heavily using active patterns, but it works in two steps - first it tokenizes the input (turning `list<char>` into `list<Token>`) and then it parses the list of tokens (turning `list<Token>` into `list<Statement>`).

This way, you mostly avoid the issue with nesting, because most interesting things become just a single token. For example, for operators, the tokenization looks like:

```
let rec tokenize toks = function
  (* First character is number, collect all remaining number characters *)
  | c::cs when isNumber c -> number toks [c] cs
  (* First character is operator, collect all remanining operator characters *)
  | c::cs when isOp c -> operator toks [c] cs
  (* more cases omitted *)
  | [] -> List.rev toks

and number toks acc = function
  | c::cs when isNumber c -> number toks (c::acc) cs
  | input -> tokenize (Number(float (str acc))::toks) input

and operator toks acc = function
  | c::cs when isOp c -> operator toks (c::acc) cs
  | input -> tokenize (Operator(List.rev acc)::toks) input
```

If you now have a list of tokens, then parsing a binary expression becomes:

```
let rec parseBinary left = function
  | (Operator o)::toks -> 
      let right, toks = parseExpr toks
      Binary(o, left, right), toks
  | toks -> left, toks

and parseExpr = function
  | (Number n)::toks -> parseBinary (Const(NumberValue n)) toks
  (* more cases omitted *)
```

There are some places where I used active patterns, for example to parse a BASIC range expression which can be `N1-N2` or `-N1` or `N1-`

```
let (|Range|_|) = function
  | (Number lo)::(Operator ['-'])::(Number hi)::[] -> 
      Some(Some (int lo), Some (int hi))
  | (Operator ['-'])::(Number hi)::[] -> Some(None, Some(int hi))
  | (Number lo)::(Operator ['-'])::[] -> Some(Some(int lo), None)
  | [] -> Some(None, None)
  | _ -> None
```

So, I guess the answer is that if you want to write a simple parser using pattern matching (without getting into more sophisticated and more powerful monadic parser libraries), then it is quite doable, but it is good idea to separate tokenization from parsing.

Comment: That could be a solution but for the porpuses of this parser the batching of operators will not work, and I am already doing it with number values and string values, since they can and most of the times will be used in a context where we need to split them in multiple tokens and your expression parser would need a post-analiser  to fix operators precedence